# Firebase Typescript initialization isse

Tags: typescript, firebase

I am trying to add firebase to a typescript app, but am having issues with the initial configuration. I have set the google side of the equation up and am using that in the config. Nonetheless, I am having issues:

```js
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/database";

// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
  //fields below purposefully redacted
  apiKey: "",
  authDomain: "",
  projectId: "",
  storageBucket: "",
  messagingSenderId: "",
  appId: "",
};

// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export default firebase.database(firebaseConfig["appId"]);
```

Error:

```
Property 'database' does not exist on type 'typeof import("c:////Documents/GitHub//node_modules/firebase/app/dist/app/index")'.ts(2339)
```

Below are pics of the issue:

[code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nEni2.png)

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQReW.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `V9.0.0+` then you should [upgrade to new Modular Syntax](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade#get_the_version_9_sdk) which looks like this:

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app"
import { getDatabase } from "firebase/database"

const app = initializeApp({...config})

const db = getDatabase(app)

export { db }
```

Make sure you are using the new syntax everywhere else in the code. Refer the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write) to learn more about the new syntax.

If you wish to use the older name-spaced syntax (as in most of the older tutorials), use the `compat` version:

```
import firebase from "firebase/compat/app";
import "firebase/compat/database";
// import "firebase/compat/[SERVICE_NAME]"
```